# Android : Device 2.3.3 work well. But Device 4.0.3 don't work. Load Image

Tags: android

Android : Device 2.3.3 work well. But Device 4.3 ( HTC One), 4.2.2 don't work. Load Image

'public static Bitmap getBitmapFroUrl(String url) {

```
    URL m;
    InputStream i = null;
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream out =null;
    try {
        m = new URL(url);
        URLConnection connection = m.openConnection();
        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConnection.connect();

            if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                i = httpConnection.getInputStream();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(i,1024 * 8);
        out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int len=0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while((len = bis.read(buffer)) != -1){
            out.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        byte[] data = out.toByteArray();  
        out.close(); 
        bis.close();
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds=true;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length,options);        
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }

}'
```

I Don't know Why? Please Help Me. Thanks !

I Know : Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length,options);

bitmap = null ( 4.2.2, 4.3)

bitmap not null ( 2.3.3 )

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using network on the UI thread. You need to access network in other thread. Have a look at [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Remeber to add these permissions:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>`

```
class BitmapGetter extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Drawable> {
    @Override
    protected Drawable doInBackground(String... params) {
        Drawable bmpRet = null;
        try {
            BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(params[0]).openStream());
            bmpRet = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in));
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {return null;}
        return bmpRet;
    }

    public void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {
        try {
            (findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setBackgroundDrawable(result);
        } catch (Exception ex) {}
    }
}
```

and execute it from Main class:

```
    new BitmapGetter().execute("https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuhXg.jpg");
```

Comment: just replace `http://i.stack.imgur.com/MuhXg.jpg` with `http://54.248.228.197/image/cover/front_pic.jpg`

Comment: i tried but didn't worked. Please check again! Android 4.http://i.stack.imgur.com/MuhXg.jpg << work well

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MuhXg.jpg   <<<< Work well. But 
http://54.248.228.197/image/cover/front_pic.jpg <<< Decode return False. Please ! Thanks

Comment: new BitmapGetter().execute(" **http://** http://54.248.228.197/image/cover/front_pic.jpg");